# Aligning two divs next to each other with scrollable feature

Tags: html, css

I started to learn HTML / CSS and I am having a problem with aligning two divs in a scrollable div. For better understanding I am going to share my code. If someone can help me I am going to be really grateful. Thank you in advance.

The idea is every "Test" class to have 100% width and to be aligned one after another in a row while the class "Box" have a scrollable feature.

```css
.Wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:90vw;
  background-color:blue;
}

.Box{
  display;
  position:relative;
  width:100%
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.Test{
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Box">
      <div class="Test">
        Test 1  
      </div>
      <div class="Test">
        Test 2  
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best regards,

George S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this is one solution to achieve it. This solution forces every child element of box to be in one row (`white-space: nowrap`), if it is an `inline` or `inline-block` element. Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rq98w432/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="Box">
    <div class="Test">
      Test 1  
    </div>
    <div class="Test">
      Test 2  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Box{
  width:90vw;
  background-color:blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```